# Cannot connect to server on hotspot connection using socket

Tags: python, android, sockets, wifi, hotspot

I am writing an app for android which creates a client. The server(a PC) is connected to this mobile via wifi. But it seems the server is not able to listen the client.
I've tried to reverse the client-server position, then the client (PC) shows ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]. Please help.

**Code for Client**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button create,close;
    TextView tv;

    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Handler updateConvHandler;
    Thread serverThread=null;
    static final int PortNo=6000;
    private static  String My_IP="192.168.43.140";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        create=findViewById(R.id.btn);
        close=findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        tv=findViewById(R.id.textview);

        create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                createClient();

            }
        });
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                closeClient();
            }
        });


    }



    private void closeClient() {
        try {
            socket.close();
            Log.e("This", "closeClient: "+"Socket closed" );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }


    private void createClient() {
        Log.e("This", "createClient: Client Is up" );
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                //Log.e("Here", "run: "+"Trying to reach" );
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(My_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr,PortNo);
                //socket.connect();

                Log.e("TAG", "run: "+"Successful"+socket.getLocalAddress() );
                OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream commStream = new DataOutputStream(stream);
                commStream.write("Hello From Client".getBytes());

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("This", "run: uhe" );
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("This", "run: ioe" );
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**Code for server**

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.43.140',6000))
print("server is up")
s.listen(5)
conn,addr=s.accept()
print("client connected ",addr)
#msg=str(input("Message?\n>"))
#conn.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
data=(conn.recv(1024)).decode('utf-8')

print(data)

conn.close()
```

**The logcat shows Timeout Exception**

Comment: Have you tried debugging network traffic using Wireshark or tcpdump?

Comment: @jeremy no idea about it.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine. Have you checked that MY_IP reflects your actual PC's IP? Your PC's firewall might block incoming connections for your python server. For further debugging of network traffic, you might find Wireshark to be useful. You can download Wireshark for all major platforms here: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Do not bind the server to an ip address. And if you have to to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: `My_IP="192.168.43.140"` Whose ip is that?

Comment: @blackapps This is the wifi ip that i got from ipconfig. If i'm right, isn't 0.0.0.0 a local host ip? But im woking with real ip, on two different devices.

Comment: thank you @jeremy . Will try it out.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a localhost ip. 0.0.0.0 is no ip.

Comment: `ip that i got from ipconfig. ` I did not ask how you got that ip but whose ip it was.

Comment: Its my pc's ip.

Comment: It seems the Firewall was the problem. Fixed it and is working fine. Thank you all.